# Algorithm for simulating burst errors

Tags: algorithm, math, simulation

I am wanting to simulate error bursts for my program but I am not sure how I would go about doing it.

Let's say I have a fixed bit-error-rate of 2/10 and varying error-burst-lengths from 4 to 12 bits and an infinite stream of bits, how can I make it so error-bursts occur at random intervals with varying lengths from 4 to 12 bits while still ensuring the average bit-error-rate converges toward 2/10?

Comment: I think you'll have better luck posting on http://math.stackexchange.com/ or http://dsp.stackexchange.com/. I can make some naive guesses as to how to approach your problem, but I don't claim to have any expertise in probability or signal processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you uniformly sample the set `[4, 5, ..., 12]` when it comes to choosing the length of an error bit burst. Then the expected length of an error burst is `(4+5+...+12)/9 = 8`.

*Note: you can sample the error burst lengths however you want - all that we actually use below is the **expectation** of the error burst length.*

If you want an overall bit error rate of `2/10`, all you have to do is the following:

```
error_lengths = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
loop forever
    if rand() < 1/33 // with probability 1/33
         n = rand(error_lengths) // pick a random error length
         emit n contiguous error bits
    else
         emit 1 good bit
```

The reason this works is that, on average, for every 33 iterations the `if` condition is `true` 1 time and `false` 32 times. Each `true` creates, on average, 8 error bits; each `false` creates 1 good bit.

Therefore the rate of error bits is `(1*8)/(1*8 + 32*1) = 8/40 = 2/10`.

---

## Edit

If you want to guarantee that no two error sequences are ever adjacent, you can do this instead:

```
error_lengths = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
loop forever
    if rand() < 1/32 // with probability 1/32
         n = rand(error_lengths) // pick a random error length
         emit n contiguous error bits
    emit 1 good bit
```

Expected number of good bits per iteration = 1
Expected number of error bits per iteration = 8/32

Error rate = (8/32)/(1+8/32) = 8/40 = 2/10

Comment: Nice approach, except it will occasionally yield back-to-back error sequences which could exceed the specified maximum sequence length of 12.  You should force at least one non-error before resuming the geometric sampling, and adjust the mean down by one accordingly.

Comment: @pjs The OP didn't actually specify that the error bursts must be non-adjacent... I've updated to supply the algorithm for that case anyway.

Comment: True, but I considered it implicit in specifying an upper bound for the length. Perhaps OP will clarify his intent on this.

Answer (score 0):

You told us a range but haven't specified the distribution for the error-burst lengths, nor for the clean interval lengths.  Are all values in the range equally likely, do 4's occur more frequently than 12's or vice-versa, or is, say, 6 the most common occurrence?

Let's assume you have distributions *E* for error-burst length and *C* for clean interval lengths, which have means M_*e* and M_*c*, respectively.  Then what you need to do is derive/construct a parameterization the *C* distribution so that M_*c* = 4 M_*e*. To kick-start the process, choose an error-burst with probability 0.2 vs a clean interval with probability 0.8 for your first interval.  Then alternate between error cycles and clean cycles using the *E* and *C* distributions to generate the durations.

For example, if both types of intervals follow uniform distributions, then the mean error burst length is 8 and you need clean intervals with a mean length of 32. You could achieve that with U(31,33), U(1,63), or U(10,54), for instance - all three have means of 32.

Comment: Thank you! Yes all values for the error-burst lengths are equally likely.